# Graphene Django disable suggestions "Did you mean ..."

Tags: graphql, graphene-python, graphene-django

When you post an query with syntax errors graphql/graphene makes suggestions to you. By example, sending "i", it suggest "ID".

```
query{
  users{
        i
  }
}
```

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot query field \"i\" on type \"User\". Did you mean \"id\"?",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 5,
          "column": 9
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Can suggestions be disabled?

More info: 
Syntax analysis who add suggestions is executed before the middlewares.
Apparently suggestions are made by [ScalarLeafsRule](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphql-core/blob/master/src/graphql/validation/rules/scalar_leafs.py#L9) class.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, people in graphql-core github repo is awesome, they helped to me to solve this.

So graphql-core has two relevant versions, 3 (current) and 2.3.2 (legacy).
For graphql-core 3, quoting to Cito

> Ok, if you want to keep it closed and also disable introspection it makes a little more sense. I suggest you simply set `graphql.pyutils.did_you_mean.MAX_LENGTH = 0`. I just commited a small change ffdf1b3 that makes this work a bit better.
>
> You can also ask over at https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues if they want to add some functionality to support your use case. From there it would be ported back here.

For legacy version:

```py
from graphql.validation import rules
def get_empty_suggested_field_names(schema, graphql_type, field_name):
    return []
def get_empty_suggested_type_names(schema, output_type, field_name):
    return []
rules.fields_on_correct_type.get_suggested_field_names = get_empty_suggested_field_names
rules.fields_on_correct_type.get_suggested_type_names = get_empty_suggested_type_n
```

You can place it on django settings file.

Please follow all the thread on https://github.com/graphql-python/graphql-core/issues/97